# How important are parameters in random forest regression?

Tags: random-forest

So I'm using random forest regression to predict on some data and I usually go with 25 or 50 trees and 50 random features. Currently I have only one data set to care about, but in the future more will come for which I have to create new models, eventually so many it will be difficult to tune the parameters by hand.

So I thought about writing a program that tries out different parameter following a specific scheme. For example, if the results for params 50/50 are not so great, try again with 40/50, then 60/50, then 50/40 etc. Just an idea. But a Ph.D. in ML told me that this effort is in vain as the parameters only slightly influence random forest, as it is very stable. **Can you confirm this?**

I've read through this [Question & Answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53240/practical-questions-on-tuning-random-forests) and I can confirm the variance reduction with my 25/50 vs. 50/50 approach, but it still doesn't really answers my question. Help is apprechiated :-)

Comment: you need the right kind of problem.  When you need to consider tree count is when the data drives it.  Consider the UCI data-sets and get something with ~50 columns, and ~1000 rows, and then look at how using the tree-count works.  You can also stack boosted random forests when you are working on regression models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Importance" is not a clear-cut concept. However, a coauthor of mine recently varied the `mtry` parameter (that is, the number of candidate predictors randomly chosen at each split) and recorded the resulting out-of-bag classification accuracy.

[image: classification accuracies]

Now, on the one hand, the accuracies differ by an amount that is probably not *clinically* different - just between 79.8% and 81.3%. On the other hand, the difference between `mtry=8` and `mtry=21` certainly is *statistically* significant.

So it seems like the parameter settings for your Random Forest can indeed have an impact on your accuracy. I was surprised at this myself.

(I'd rather not give details on the classification task here, because this is yet-unsubmitted work in progress, and I don't want my collaborators to kill me. I'm too young to die.)

Comment: I'm a big fan of teaching folks how to "prove it to yourself" and if you didn't give an answer of this form then I might have tried to.  It would be good, after you have published, to make this something to revisit and expand for reproducibility with a request that if they publish work after using your method to certify, that they put your paper in their references.